# Instrumental variable makes effect insignificant

Tags: instrumental-variables, confounding, endogeneity

Following is what I ran first (in STATA):

```
probit Y X CV1 CV2
```

where Y is a binary dependent variable, X is a potentially endogenous continuous regressor, CV1 and CV2 are exogenous control variables.

This gave me coefficient for X significant at 1%.

Next, I ran

```
ivprobit Y CV1 CV2 (X = Z)
```

This instruments X with Z, CV1, and CV2.

I find that post instrumenting, the coefficient for X has become insignificant.

Is this because I am forcibly introducing an instrument variable, because the Wald test for endogeneity shows that X actually has been exogenous all along?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you mean by "instrumenting" X with Z? What other specific model(s) did you estimate, or, at least, what specific procedure did you use?

Comment: It would be a really good idea to include a causal diagram for your variables $X, Y, Z, CV_1,$ and $CV_2.$